# why is newCachedThreadPool good for short-lived asynchronous tasks?

Tags: java

Javadoc says "These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks."

But I can't understand why it is so clearly.

Comment: Because the same thread will be reused when it's freed, removing the overhead of creating a new thread for every task.